# How to track user has 'disabled' my Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, permissions

I want to send log(We're using Amplitude by the way) the moment user 'disabled' Chrome Extension.

I know we can see the percentage and numbers of disabled users in the Chrome Extension Web Store page. But I want to know the funnel and exact timing when user disabled my Extension. Is there any way to do this?

First, I tried chrome.management.onDisabled. Sadly, the event triggered only when other extensions has disabled and cannot find out self being disabled. Also, it triggered permission warning, which is not desirable because we don't want to lose users(We only have tabs, clipboardRead permission). Marking as optional permission doesn't work, because if user do not agree with permission we can't use the API(chrome.management).

Second, I thought of extension notification to catch user has disabled or removed my Chrome Extension. But notifiaction also triggers permission warning and it cannot distinguish between disabled user and removed users.